# Игнорирование Регистра в JS

Tags: javascript, бот, регистрация

К примеру имеем массив:

```
let greetingsUser = ["привет", "как дела?", "здравствуй"];
```

Подобный массив читает бот, после того как принимает значение `greetingsUser[0]...` , дает ответ `..`

При этом бот не может ответить, если сказать "Привет", а не "привет", так как другой регистр.

Подскажите, как игнорировать регистр, буду очень благодарен.

Вот как бот принимает и отвечает

```
bot.hears(greetingsUser, async ctx => {
    await ctx.reply(randomGreetings(greetingsBot));
});
```

//greetingsBot - хранит ответы бота

bot - [telegraf](https://telegraf.js.org/#/).

Comment: что за `bot`  здесь?

Comment: @Grundy telegraf

Comment: добавь это в вопрос

Comment: @Grundy добавил

Comment: https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/issues/287

Comment: https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=hears . Принимает в себя не только строку, но и `Regex`, можно составить такой `regex`: `/^привет/i`

Comment: но как передать много слов а не только привет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну ведь в [документации](https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=hears) всё ж написано:

```
Param       Type                                    Description
triggers    string/string[]/RegEx/RegEx[]/Function  Triggers
```

Что бы это могло значить `RegEx/RegEx[]`?

Ну конечно же, [регулярные выражения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)!

Comment: const greetingsUserRefEx = /привет/i;



bot.hears(greetingsUserRefEx, async ctx => {
    await 
    ctx.reply(randomGreetings(greetingsBot));
  });

одно слово передаю, а масив не могу вставить туда свой

Comment: Надо составить одну или несколько регулярок `/(?:привет|(?:здравствуй(?:те)?)|(?:добро пожаловать)|аллё)/i`, можно массивом `.hears([rx1,rx2,rx3],cb)` но не обязательно.

Comment: спасибо большое ))